# MiniPlayer shows only when toggling between tabs in Flutter

Tags: flutter, tabs, dismiss

I have created a `Miniplayer` in Flutter which looks like this:

```
Miniplayer(
      controller: miniplayerController,
      minHeight: 60,
      onDismissed: (){
        context.read(selectedVideoProvider).state = null;
      },
      maxHeight: size.height - topPadding - 60,
      builder: (height, percentage){

        if (selectedVideo == null) {
          return const SizedBox.shrink();
        }

        if (height <= size.width / 16 * 9){
          return Row(
            children: [
              Text('This is a miniplayer'),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  context.read(selectedVideoProvider).state = null;
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.close)
              )
            ],
          );
        }
            
        return AnotherScreen();
      }
    );
```

Also as you can see I have a `selectedVideoProvider` `StateProvider` (I use `flutter_riverpod` for a state management). Also I wrapped my `Miniplayer` with a `Visibility` widget:

```
Consumer(
      builder: (context, watch, _){
        final selectedVideo = watch(selectedVideoProvider).state;

        
        return Visibility(maintainState: true, visible: selectedVideo != null, child: MyMiniplayerWidget());
      }
    ),
```

Here is the screen of the app:
[image]

**Miniplayer** appears when I click on these pictures in my `ListView`. When I click for the first time everything works great (miniplayer appears properly). However when i dismiss my miniplayer I can not open a new miniplayer by clicking on another picture. Only when i go to another tab (tabs are on my `bottom navigation bar`) and then go back to this screen the **miniplayer** appears with the **MIN size**:

[image]

But I want it to pop up when I click on the pictures. And again, when I click on the picture for the first time everything works great.

What is wrong with my code? Why **miniplayer** appears only when I toggle between tabs?

PS. if I make `maintainState = false` in my `Visibility` widget miniplayer appears immediately after clicking on the picture, however it appears with the MIN size, but I want it to appear in MAX size. Could you please also explain me why it doesn't work, if I make

```
context.read(miniPlayerControllerProvider).state.animateToHeight(state: PanelState.MAX);
```

this when I click on the picture (this is a `StateProvider` for my miniplayerController) (this line of code makes my miniplayer appear with MAX size when I click on the picture when `maintainState = true` in `Visibility` widget)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with miniplayer and solved it with the following code:

```
Miniplayer(
    valueNotifier: ValueNotifier(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
```